# Extending AbstractAuditable (Spring Data) causes org.hibernate.MappingException on ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to mapping my entities with JPA 2 with Hibernate as provider but unfortunately I'm having an exception, maybe known by several people, but even looking in web I could not find a soulution
I think maybe is because I'm using Spring Data JPA enviroment:

**EDIT** I removed `extends AbstractAuditable` and created the id, then the error moved to another entity with `AbstractAuditable`, so I'm using this class wrong?

The relevant part of stracktrace says:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Collection, at table: car, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(gearAssigments)]
```

The following entities involved:

GearAssigment

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gear_assigment")
public class GearAssigment extends AbstractAuditable<User, Integer> {

    private Integer usedQuantity;

    private Car car;

    private Gear gear;

    public GearAssigment(int id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public GearAssigment() {
    }

    @Column(name = "used_quantity")
    public Integer getUsedQuantity() {
        return usedQuantity;
    }

    public void setUsedQuantity(Integer usedQuantity) {
        this.usedQuantity = usedQuantity;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car",referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Car getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "gear",referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Gear getGear() {
        return gear;
    }

    public void setGear(Gear gear) {
        this.gear = gear;
    }
}
```

Car

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car extends AbstractAuditable<User, Integer> {

    private String name;

    private Category category;

    private Collection<GearAssigment> gearAssigments;

    public Car(Integer id) {
        this.setId(id);
    }

    public Car() {
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "category")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    public Collection<GearAssigment> getGearAssigments() {
        return gearAssigments;
    }

    public void setGearAssigments(Collection<GearAssigment> gearAssigments) {
        this.gearAssigments = gearAssigments;
    }
}
```

**All** tables on DB have `id` as primary key, `AbstractAuditable extends AbstractPersistable` which already map the `id colunm` with `@GeneratedValue` and they are mapped with `@MappedSuperClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, `AbstractAuditable` fields are annotated with javax.persistence annotations at field level, not at method level as I was doing on my entities, so do you override the Spring's class or annotated all entities fields at field level. So Hibernate don't mix them